# Types of site collections in SharePoint?

Tags: 2013

How many types of site collections are there in sharepoint.

Host Headers ?

Host Name Site collections ?

What else ?

Example of above ?

Answer (score 1):

*Host-named site collections* and *Path-based site collections*.

Will not copy&paste a full technet article to this answer, as it doesn't make much sense, but the differences are discussed [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx#section1b).

Regarding Web Applications, there is really just one type, but you can configure it in so many ways, so effectively you have almost unlimited number of variations. E.g., if you consider different Web Applications with different authentication types really different type of actual Web Application. You can also categorize Web Applications in different Zones. Or perhaps the root site collection template determines the Web Application type, so you have My Site web application and Intranet web applications. Or the purpose of the web application, such as Extranet web application and Team Workspace Web Application.

They're all just IIS web applications with possibly very different characteristics. Located within one IIS Application Pool or in separate ones.

Answer (score 0):

You have the Host Name Site Collections VS Path-Based Site Collections. That's it. 
The Host Header is related to the Web Application itself.

Comment: how many types of web applications ??

Comment: Web Application differ upon the type of their security mechanism, you have either "Claims based authentication" web apps, or "Classic mode authentication".